# How to delegate this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a simple function, but I think there is a delegation problem.

I dynamicaly add a class to existings elements after the page is loading. (`$(elemen).addClass('myclass-123');`)

Now I want to use this element in a function which detects if the element is resized or scrolled.

If I run this code with an element which already has the class - all works fine.

If I add a class later, this element won't work so I think its a problem with the delegation of the function and the elements, but i don't know how I can solve it.

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
   console.log("check number of elements on page: "+$("[class^='myclass-']").length);
   $("[class^='myclass-']").each(function() {... do something with the elements });
});
```

Comment: To add to @RoryMcCrossan comment, use `$(elem).addClass("'myclass-123 myclass")` then use `$(".myclass").each..` - by adding both the `-123` version and a general "all" version you can check without needing to check for class starts with.

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand you correctly - may you can give me a little example? For the prefix: i need this, there are 3 classes wich matched this functions.

Comment: @mikeD I made the comment in to an answer with an example below

Comment: `i need this, there are 3 classes wich matched this functions` in that case add a fourth which gets applied to the elements regardless of any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an event delegation problem as the elements will be selected so long as they have the class when the `resize` or `scroll` event fires.

The problem is because your selector relies on `myclass` being the first in the attribute, eg `class="myclass foo"`, yet if you're adding the class later it will be at the end of the attribute, eg `class="foo myclass"`, and hence won't be found by the attribute selector. You can confirm this in the DOM inspector.

To fix it, use `filter()` instead to find the elements where they have any class which begins with `myclass-`:

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('[class*="myclass-"]').filter(function() {
    return this.classList.some(c => c.indexOf('myclass-') == 0);
  }).each(function() {
    // do something with the elements 
  });
});
```

Note that the above can be made simpler if you add a single class to all the elements instead of a prefixed dynamic one.

Comment: thanks a lot, now i understand what you mean and what is the problem. By using your suggested code i recieve "TypeError: $(...).classList is undefined"!?

Comment: it seems to work also with "$("[class*='webcms-onscroll-']")" changing the selector from ^= to *=

Comment: Apologies about the error - it should be `this.classList`, not `$(this).classList`